# Android - Storing fair amounts of data locally, xml/json or SQLite?

Tags: android, xml, json, sqlite, storage

Long story short: I'm working on refactoring an old Android project of mine. Previously, it was using serialization, which was painfully slow and, from what I'm reading, a pretty lousy idea in general for Android apps. I'm looking for another way to persist both user-specific data as well and read-only data for the application.

There is going to be a good deal of data on both sides and I'm not sure if there's a "good" way to store it. Basically, the app is a small RPG. There are a number of "maps" that are represented as 2D arrays of Tiles. Each Tile will have a number of attributes, some simple primitives or enums, others additional objects, such as Events, which will also potentially contain various objects, etc. With 400 Tiles in a 20x20 map alone, there's a LOT of data to store. In addition to storing that data, it would need to store a lot of user-specific data, such as which Tiles have been visited, which Events have been successfully run, etc.

I've been examining methods of saving this data out and I just can't seem to settle on something. I guess it boils down to XML or JSON vs SQLite. XML or JSON would be more flexible in terms of future changes, which is good as I want flexibility in the data, ie, adding new attributes to existing objects, adding new objects as the need arises, etc. SQLite isn't as easily malleable as you have to change up the schema, perhaps adjust queries and indexes, etc, but I haven't really used SQLite in the past, so maybe there are some features that help to simplify that process. However, I would also like fast random access to data to avoid loading everything into memory at once if it can be helped. For example, when moving from one map to another, I'd much rather load the next map only when needed rather than having everything held in memory, which is where SQLite would shine as I'd be able to directly query the data rather than traversing a JSON/XML file to find potentially scattered data, ie, we load the map, but Events and objects contained in the Events may not be unique to that map and could easily lie elsewhere in the file or in another file entirely. However, normalizing the data in SQLite would mean a lot of tables and quite a bit of deconstructing/reconstructing of objects.

Writing user data would only occur when the user manually saves the game, so write performance is not a big issue.

I sometimes have a tendency to overanalyze and get hung up on stuff like this. Maybe neither case is necessarily "wrong" and I'm worrying about things that are infinitesimal. Maybe there are other cases that I haven't considered. I've used Hibernate and have considered something like ORMLite to handle a lot of the database nitty-gritty, but that would require a lot of retrofitting, likely much more than what I would need to do for other options.

Comment: Have you looked at Active Android? http://www.activeandroid.com/

Comment: You could also consider [CouchBaseLite-Android](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android), which gives you greater flexibility in contents, but doesn't query as easily as SQLite. There's also the option of using an index structure directories of XML/JSON files (as opposed to a single, massive file), like git does to great effect.

Comment: One of the options is to use our SolFS virtual filesystem ( https://www.eldos.com/solfs/ ). It offers flexible storage, tags for files and sql-like file search.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use SQLite.  I think it makes the most sense considering the amount of data you're trying to store.

As far as your concerns with it not being as flexible, I would argue that point.  Just use a ContentProvider.  ContentProviders make it pretty easy to update the db schema and queries without affecting your existing functionality.   If you use a ContentProvider, you could even swap out persistent data strategies in the future as well as use different ones simultaneously.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html