# How to store Data for program logic in Android Development in Java?

Tags: java, android, xml, json, sqlite

I'm currently designing an app that will assist players of a board game by helping randomly select an element of it within certain constraints such as setting expansions owned, house-rules, banned cards, plus same more complex stuff.

If I were designing this as a website, I'd use a database to hold all the data on the cards I'll be randomising, but on android I'm unsure what would be the best approach to store the data in.

I'd rather not have the app communicate with a server to keep it offline compatible. I also need to be able to update the data store when I update the app so I can support future expansions.

I'm planning on using Java to develop as it would keep development time short, and my app wouldn't benefit from the performance that C++ would provide. But I've only developed for Android once in the past, and my Java knowledge is much worse than my C++.

Reading in this question, [Android - Storing fair amounts of data locally, xml/json or SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394225/android-storing-fair-amounts-of-data-locally-xml-json-or-sqlite), it seems I have three choices: XML, JSON, or SQLite. I'm familiar with the first two, but wouldn't know how to package any of them inside a self-contained apk.

The data I'm storing is currently 50 entries long and comprises of integers, strings, booleans, and HTML-formatted text about individual cards. I'd also like to store 64 card thumbnail images of about 10KB each locally too. Each expansion adds approximately 15-20 to the list.

What would be the best way to store this and how do I package this all in a single apk?

While researching this I've learnt of the new Android Studio, and will likely use that, however I used Eclipse with ADT in the past but my knowledge of it is still pretty limited. Assume development in Windows, total beginner knowledge of both IDEs and Android/Java development in general; as even though I've used Java before on both Android and PC I'm fairly sure my last app broke quite a few 'best practice rules'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your data is actually quite small I think that an XML/JSON solution will be appropriate.

As to including static data files in your apk Android provides easy solutions.
Arbitrary assets can be included in the same way as graphics etc. You can use the raw directory for resources of this type. [This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) should help you with that.

As for tools if you are unfamiliar with both it seems the Android Studio is the way of the future so use that - it is reliable and pretty solid on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for that, and I've been getting to grips with Android studio. Does it always use a gigantic amount of memory?